How to adjust for p-values in Kruskal Wallis test with two or more hypothesis
I need help adjusting for p-values. I have a cohort of 200 patients. I am using 3 metrics to divide this group into different categories. Here is how they are distributed.



Metric A Category
Number of patients




None
120


Mild
55


Moderate
20


Severe
5






Metric B Category
Number of patients




Low risk
125


Medium risk
55


High risk
20






Metric C Category
Number of patients




Disease
160


Without disease
40



I am interested in whether there are significant differences in the body mass index and apolipoprotein A levels between groups of Metric A. I am also interested in the same variables but for Metric B. And also for Metric C. I decided to use Kruskal-Wallis tests since none of the metrics had distributions that satisfied the assumptions of ANOVA.
I originally used the Bonferroni method with an alpha of 0.05 to correct the p-values yielded by the Kruskal-Wallis tests. Since I was interested in two variables, apolipoprotein A and body mass index, I thought I should use a m =2. This yielded me an adjusted p-value of 0.025. I used this p-value threshold to determine which results from The Kruskal-Wallis tests were significant.
Only Metric A had p-values < 0.025. Afterward, I used a Conover-Iman test with an alpha of 0.05 and a p-adjustment with Holm-Bonferroni method to determine whether apolipoprotein A and BMI were different between groups in Metric A.
However, I am not sure if this is the right approach. From posts in this site, some suggest using all the number of hypothesis testing to  adjust for p. Using the example of the post, this would be (4 * 2) + (3 * 2) + (2 * 2) = 18 in my case. So m = 18, which would give me a threshold of p < 0.002. The other approach I saw is to just do the p-value adjustment after a post-hoc test without any correction beforehand. Which is the correct approach?

You wrote I decided to use Kruskal-Wallis tests since none of the metrics had distributions that satisfied the assumptions of ANOVA. Note that for ANOVA, there are no distributional assumptions re. the marginal distributions, but only for the residuals (normality of residuals is the only assumption, as homoscedasticity is not needed for the Welch-version of the ANOVA). So you may want to try ANOVA, and see what the residuals really look like...

The Kruskal-Wallis and Wilcoxon tests are special cases of the proportional odds semiparametric ordinal logistic regression model.  It would be better to place the analysis in that context.  That way you can make any contrasts of interest, and deal with multiple $X$ variables simultaneously.  See this for resources, and don't make the mistake of doing any binning to use the prop. odds model.
